# Passport book cover is slightly detached from page

Tags: air-travel, passports, indian-citizens, india

My Indian passport book cover is detached from the main book, but all other information, as well as the book is fine. I am traveling to India in 2 days.
What should I do? Will there any problem at the airport?

Comment: You are going home, they should not stop you for damage, but you would be well advised to get a replacement once you are back in India.  To be double certain, if there is an India Embassy nearby, report the damage and ask if you need an emergency travel document.

Comment: @pnuts - Yeah I am sure some googling master will create an encyclopedic answer with snippets copied from authoritative websites, complimented by links to two dozen expert opinions and perhaps an image or two of damaged passports.

Comment: Thanks for reply ,I went to Indian consulate and as per them there will be no problem and there is no need of emergency travel document.

Answer (score 3):

**You should be ok**.

From what you describe, your passport isn't damaged in a way that makes it unreadable or unrecognizable, as defined by the [Indian Ministry of External Affairs](http://passportindia.gov.in/AppOnlineProject/online/faqLostDamagedPassports).

> Q1:   What is the definition of damaged passport? A:  Damaged passport is
>   classified further based on the extent of damage, i.e.: Damaged
>   Passport - Passport number is readable, name is legible and photo is
>   intact Damaged beyond recognition

So entering should not be a problem. If you're still concerned you can still get an [emergency travel document](http://www.immihelp.com/nri/indianpassport/emergency-travel-document.html) which is a one way travel document issued to Indian citizens who have lost or damaged their passports and need to travel to India on an emergency.