# Indian Passport thread coming off

Tags: india

We gave our passport for stamping and it looks like it returned with threads coming out lose. My passport has only 2 threads remaining.

We are travelling to a couple of countries before going to India (And then get visa stamped).

Did anyone visit the consulate and can they fix it? It should work with a glue but I dont want to mess with passorts.

Comment: Welcome to TSE. You may want to check *[Indian passport threading coming off](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/87562)* and *[Passport book cover is slightly detached from page](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/80198/)* to see if they answer your questions.

Comment: Can I get the contract for printing and producing Indian passports. Dog gone it, they must be the most poorly constructed passports in the whole wide world and galaxy.