# Can I travel to Canada with this passport on student visa it's my first international travel?

Tags: canada, international-travel, damaged-passports

[image]I KEPT MY PASSPORT INSIDE A COLOURFUL FOLDER BECAUSE OF WHICH IT GOT THIS MARKINGS ON THE HARD COVER REST EVERYTHING IS INTACT AND ALL THE PAGES ARE NEW.

Comment: Related question https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/80198/passport-book-cover-is-slightly-detached-from-page

Comment: I doubt you'd have trouble in most places, but especially not in Canada.  Passport covers can become worn.  Red flags will fly if there are any signs that the passport has been altered or tampered with.  That doesn't appear to be the case here.

Comment: Please do not type in ALL CAPITALS. It's perceived as shouting, and is considered impolite. Thank you.